# How/which format to create multi-page printable documents with precise geometry/layout?

Tags: svg, latex, postscript

I would like to automatically generate calendar pages with very specific information and a very specific layout and ideally have all pages in a single document (can be PDF, doesn't have to be). For they layout of the boxes, text placement etc. I would like to be able to control the geometry very precisely so it's the same on every page and reproducible.

I could create SVG with exact dimensions, but I'm not sure about the part where I actually turn it into a document for printing.
With LaTeX I can most likely generate what I would like to have, but am unsure whether I have precise enough control over the dimensions of all my elements.
Creating Postscript or even a PDF "from scratch" seems a little too intimidating.

I know there may be more than one solution to this, but I'm happy to explore several options and see what works best with my experience.

Comment: I think it is objectively answerable, but there may be more than one valid answer. Any format that has printable pages and can be automatically generated, containing layout elements with precise geometry is acceptable. My calendar example may be too specific, it could be technical drawings or anything else needs to be replicated with precise dimensions. Is there such a thing as a "community wiki" type answer that collects all valid answers here on SO, or does that only exist on some (other) Stackexchange sites?

Answer (score 1):

I can give some kind of answer for the PostScript ecosystem, much less for latex or svg.

If you have multiple images with identical dimensions, say

```
image1.eps image2.eps ... imageN.eps
```

you can write a simple PostScript *script* to tie them together. Something like

```
0 0 moveto
(image1.eps) run
0 100 moveto
(image2.eps) run
0 200 moveto
(image3.eps) run
...
500 700 moveto
(imageN.eps) run
showpage
```

To run this script with Ghostscript you'll need to add `-dNOSAFER` to the command line in order to enable the `run` operator. This script also assume *fully* compliant EPS files that don't do any funny stuff like calling `showpage` themselves.

There are also command line tools like `psnup` (usually packaged with other tools as `psutils` from whereever you got GhostScript) which can produce simple tiled layouts from separate pages.

For the specific example of generating calendar pages, I happen to have [a few postscript programs which do this](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/calendar). `gridcal.ps` creates a neat format where all the months are side by side in columns and the weeks are shown by shading Saturday and Sunday. `cal3.ps` can generate more normal formats with the days of the week for the columns.

Answer (score 0):

I went with automatically creating SVGs, using dimensions in millimeters and the viewport in the same size, so I could create my geometry very simple in exactly the way I want. I converted them to PDF using Inkscape on the command line. I haven't tried actually merging all pages into one document yet.